# CSS: Why use style classes when i can target them?

Tags: html, css

I wonder about something, why should i name classes and style them, when i can just target then with css3 pseudo-classes? Will not be lesser "html code"?

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#link1" class="menu smoothScroll">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#link2" class="menu smoothScroll">Link 2</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

In my CSS instead of i style the menu like this

```
.menu { 
background-color: red;
width 50px;
}
```

I can just write like this?

```
header nav a:link { 
background-color: red;
width 50px;
}
```

This is just an demostration/example i wrote fast, because if this is "smarter" or "better" coding then alot of webpages can get rid of alot unncesseriy classes and divs then they just target them as an Child-element?

Is this better or not?

Comment: It has to do with scalability, if your project gets larger you might encounter instances where you'll need to write similar HTML than you did above. In those cases it might not be preferable to have the same CSS applied to that code.

Comment: This is probably going to get marked down as not a proper Stack Overflow question... Is it better or not is opinion on some levels. But the answer to your question is no, it is not better. It has do to with managing complexity, as a front end gets complex, which also normally means it looks nice, you have to have a very tight sophisticated order to your front end and this means using classes.

Comment: That was some really awesome answer, and fast ones :D! My projekt is very small its a one page portfolio and i want to write the code correct from the beginning, thats why im asking!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: because it makes things easier.

It may be:

- very difficult to write specific rules to target very specific elements
- impossible to target elements directly if the HTML is very dynamic
- cumbersome to add a lot of specific selectors if you want to style several elements the same in different parts of the document
- difficult to move elements around in the document, because you need to touch the CSS rules as well every time

Classes identify groups of elements which you all want to treat equally, completely independently of their position within the document. This enables you to decouple your CSS and your document structure and reuse CSS efficiently for different documents.

Answer (score 0):

The content of a web is often (very often) dinamic. that means it is developed in a team when (in my case) I do all the styles and they do all the programing stuff. You may have a container (div) and you may know what is going to be inside (links) but you will never know if you may have one or 200 links inside. You can control the html container and give it a class but even if my mates could make that any link inside has a class as it is generated, why bother them if I can target perfectly the links through `header nav a:link`

Comment: and @deceze answered you faster (while I was writting) with a much, much better explanation